# Iterate the Json and build new json in python

Tags: python, json

I want to iterate ad extract specific keys build new json from the below json.

Input:

```
{
 "httpRequest":{"status":200}, 
 "protoPayload":{"rid":"1","resource":"/food/android?event_name=afo_product1_clicked", 
 "startTime":"2021-04-12T07:26:02.019507Z"}, 
 "receiveTimestamp":"2021-04-12T07:26:02.176159139Z"
 },

{ 
"httpRequest":{"status":200}, 
"protoPayload":{"rid":"2", "resource":"/food/android?event_name=afo_addtocart_clicked", 
"startTime":"2021-04-12T07:26:02.019507Z"}, 
"receiveTimestamp":"2021-04-12T07:26:02.176159139Z"
 }
```

expected output:

```
  {"rid":"1","resource":"/food/android?event_name=afo_product1_clicked"}
 ,{"rid":"2","resource":"/food/android?event_name=afo_addtocart_clicked"}
```

Comment: Try the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/json.html?highlight=json#module-json) module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current `json` is not valid and cannot be loaded as it has no boundary square brackets `[]`.

If you cannot fix this in your input data, we can add them manually. This is because its better to handle `json` correctly and handle it as a `json` object and not a `string`.

```
import json

string = '''{
 "httpRequest":{"status":200}, 
 "protoPayload":{"rid":"1","resource":"/food/android?event_name=afo_product1_clicked", 
 "startTime":"2021-04-12T07:26:02.019507Z"}, 
 "receiveTimestamp":"2021-04-12T07:26:02.176159139Z"
 },

{ 
"httpRequest":{"status":200}, 
"protoPayload":{"rid":"2", "resource":"/food/android?event_name=afo_addtocart_clicked", 
"startTime":"2021-04-12T07:26:02.019507Z"}, 
"receiveTimestamp":"2021-04-12T07:26:02.176159139Z"
 }'''

string = '[' + string + ']'

output = []
json_string = json.loads(string)

for entry in json_string:
    payload = entry.get('protoPayload')
    if payload:
        data = {}
        data['rid'] = payload.get('rid')
        data['resource'] = payload.get('resource')
        output.append(data)

output
#[{'rid': '1', 'resource': '/food/android?event_name=afo_product1_clicked'}, {'rid': '2', 'resource': '/food/android?event_name=afo_addtocart_clicked'}]
```

If we only want the `event_name` parameter to be stored, we can change our loop to:

```
import re

for entry in json_string:
        payload = entry.get('protoPayload')
        if payload:
            data = {}
            url = re.search('(.*?(?=\?))(?:\?event_name=)(.*)', payload.get('resource'))
            data['rid'] = payload.get('rid')
            data['lob'] = url.group(1).replace('/', '')
            data['event_name'] = url.group(2)
            output.append(data)

output
#[{'rid': '1', 'lob': 'foodandroid', 'event_name': 'afo_product1_clicked'}, {'rid': '2', 'lob': 'foodandroid', 'event_name': 'afo_addtocart_clicked'}]
```

Comment: PacketLoss : works well

Comment: both solution works well.... i want to split with non key from the input and make like following. for ex:  [{'rid': '1',  'lob'= 'foodandroid', 'event_name'='afo_product1_clicked'}, {'rid': '2',  'lob'= 'foodandroid', 'event_name'='afo_addtocart_clicked'}] .

Comment: @thiru I have updated the regex in the second part of the answer to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can get the data to a format of a list of dicts like below, you can use the following:
Edit: I added some code to include the `event_name` key

```
data = [{
 "httpRequest":{"status":200}, 
 "protoPayload":{"rid":"1","resource":"/food/android?event_name=afo_product1_clicked", 
 "startTime":"2021-04-12T07:26:02.019507Z"}, 
 "receiveTimestamp":"2021-04-12T07:26:02.176159139Z"
 },

{ 
"httpRequest":{"status":200}, 
"protoPayload":{"rid":"2", "resource":"/food/android?event_name=afo_addtocart_clicked", 
"startTime":"2021-04-12T07:26:02.019507Z"}, 
"receiveTimestamp":"2021-04-12T07:26:02.176159139Z"
 }]


res = []

for subdict in data:
    res.append({"rid":subdict["protoPayload"]["rid"],"resource":subdict["protoPayload"]["resource"],
                 "event_name":subdict["protoPayload"]["resource"].split("event_name=")[1]})

print(res)
```

output:

```
[{'rid': '1', 'resource': '/food/android?event_name=afo_product1_clicked', 'event_name': 'afo_product1_clicked'}, {'rid': '2', 'resource': '/food/android?event_name=afo_addtocart_clicked', 'event_name': 'afo_addtocart_clicked'}]
```

NOTE: The code is pretty ugly and there's probably a cleaner way to do it, but for the sake of getting it done, you can use this.

Comment: Thanks Vedank. is it possible to split the resource object into multiple key,value paris...like [{'rid': '1', event_name=afo_product1_clicked'} , {'rid': '2', event_name= afo_addtocart_clicked'}]

Comment: I'll edit the answer to include that